# PDF navigation to specific page based on selected options

Tags: javascript, pdf, navigation

I am trying to create a dynamic PDF form. Page one has 3 drop down menus. Based on the selection of the options from these menus, I want the navigate or go to button on the first page to take me to a certain page within the document. I know I would have to use Javascript for this but can't get around to having the button read the active values of the drop down. Do I need to add some script to the drop down menus as well to declare their value?

Comment: I already found that link. while I was able to create buttons that take me to a specific page, I wasn't able to use the state of the combobox to use as an if condition to take me to a specific page. I was unable to read the values from the comboboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys. I found the answer to my question. I was making a mistake in the syntax and missed a curly bracket.

```
if (this.getField("Type").value == "Transformer"){
  if (this.getField("Size").value == "220") {
    if (this.getField("HS").value == "Yes") {
      this.pageNum = 2
    } else {
      this.pageNum = 1
    }  
  }
}
```